# Mobile Fu not responding to session[:mobile_view]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mobile

Mobile Fu seems to be working great, except for one thing... I'm trying to manually set session[:mobile_view] to false, but the mobile format is still rendered. The only way to force it is to do 'request.format = :html'. A simple example of this is:

```
has_mobile_fu(true)
before_filter(:check_mobile)

def check_mobile
  session[:mobile_view] = false
end
```

Then, in my home_controller, if I check 'is_mobile_view?' it returns true (even though session[:mobile_view] is false). The reason I am doing this is so that I can allow the user to switch between Full Site and Mobile Site. Seems pretty straightforward.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I met with the same issue and I opened an issue as below:

https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu/issues/27

I actually solved this issue by modifying the method is_mobile_device? a bit. Hope that helps you too..

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from the [readme](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mobile-fu/1.3.1/frames):

> If you want to use the default response templates, like
>   index.html.erb, instead of the index.tablet.erb you can exclude the
>   tablet rendering from beeing used: you can create a before_filter and
>   *put it before* the has_mobile_fu call

Looking at your question you have the filter *after* the has_mobile_fu call.

This is the code excerpt that accompanies the above text:

```
before_filter :force_tablet_html
has_mobile_fu

def force_tablet_html
    session[:tablet_view] = false
end
```